# Are Database connections asynchronous in Node?

Tags: node.js, database, asynchronous

Node is single-threaded, but there are a lot of functions(modules like http, fs) that allow us to do a background task and the event loop takes care of executing the callbacks.

However, is this true for a database connection?
Let's say I have the following code.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

function callDatabase(id) {
    var result;
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host        :   '192.168.1.14',
            user        :   'root',
            password    :   '',
            database    :   'test'
        }
    );

    connection.connect();
    var queryString = 'SELECT name FROM test WHERE id = 1';

    connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        for (var i in rows) {
            result = rows[i].name;
        }

        connection.end();
        return result;
    });
}
```

Does, `mysql.createConnection, connection.connect, connection.query, connection.end` spin up a new thread to execute in the background, leaving Node to run the remaining synchronous code?

If yes, in what queue will the callback be enqueued and how to write this sort of code such that a background task is initiated.

Comment: All thing is node is asynchronous .The cool thing about asynchronous programing is that,it use single thread, So It dosen't have to create *Expensive* thread, This is one of the main reason of Async programing... Even node can't create thread, Also you can't Block async behavior In node,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that may be blocking (file system operations, network connections, etc) are generally asynchronous in Node, in order to avoid blocking on the main thread. That these functions take a parameter for a callback function is a sure hint that you have asynchronous operations (or "background tasks") in progress.

You don't show it in your sample code, but `connect()` and `end()` do take callback functions so you know when a connection is actually made or ends. It looks like the `mysql` library, however, also maintains an internal queue to make sure you can't attempt a query until a connection has been made and that only one operation at a time can be executed.

Note that `createConnection()` does *not* have a callback function. All it does is create a new data structure (`connection`) that gets used. It doesn't do any I/O itself, so doesn't need to run asynchronously.

Also note that you don't generally "spin up" your own threads. Node takes care of this thread management for you (largely by running things on the main worker thread), for the most part, and hides how threads themselves work for most developers. You typically hear that Node is "single threaded", and you should treat it this way.

Modern Node code makes extensive use of async/await and Promises to do this sort of thing. Slightly older code uses callback functions. Even older code uses Node events. In reality - if you dig far enough down, they're all using events and possibly presenting the simplified (more modern) interfaces.

The [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) appears to date from the "callback" era and hasn't yet been updated for Promises/async/await. Under the covers, as noted, it uses Node events to track network (or unix domain socket) connections and transfers.

Comment: > "The mysql module appears to date from the "callback" era and hasn't yet been updated for Promises/async/await." But we can `promisify` it of course.

Comment: yes, but it isn't so straightforward with `promisify` since `connection.query()` takes a callback that expects three parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039289/nodejs-util-promisify-where-the-callback-function-has-multiple-arguments for some possible approaches.

Comment: @Prisoner thanks for your kind explanation, I still have a doubt on how these functions run 'at the background', for instance, let's take connection.query(), is it under the hood performing a fetch() request?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify further. You can think of it that way, if you wish, tho the reality is that it predates fetch() and uses Node events to handle the network or UNIX socket connection.